# Obtener los valores 0 de una cuenta cuando no hay coincidencias en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a la base de datos y tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
Producto | Color |
------------------
Camiseta |Azul   |
Camiseta |Rojo   |
Gorra    |Verde  |
```

Estoy intentando hacer un consulta que me saque lo siguiente:

```
Producto | Color | Cantidad 
---------------------------
Camiseta |Azul   | 1
Camiseta |Rojo   | 1
Camiseta |Verde  | 0
Gorra    |Azul   | 0
Gorra    |Rojo   | 0
Gorra    |Verde  | 1
```

Es decir, que me saque los valores a `0` de los colores en los que no encuentre nada.

Actualmente tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT producto, color, count(*) as cantidad
FROM productos
GROUP BY producto, color
```

He probado varias cosas que he visto en Internet, pero no me cuadra nada.

Comment: La base de datos no la tienes normalizada. ¿Prefieres una solución sin normalzarla o prefieres que te digamos la forma correcta de crear las tablas y cómo se haría en ese caso?

Comment: La forma correcta. Ya que la tabla que he puesto ahí es de ejemplo para que se entendiera más facilmente.

Comment: Respuesta con la base de datos modificada, pero te puedo dar también una solución para tal y como la tienes ahora mismo.

Comment: Ya te he agregado una respuesta sin necesidad de cambiar el esquema de tu base de datos. Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a [cómo se normalizan las bases de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu base de datos está diseña correctamente entonces basta con usar un `LEFT JOIN` entre todas las combinaciones posibles de colores y productos y contar aquellas que no sean `NULL`:

```
SELECT
  p.producto,
  c.color,
  COUNT(lp.producto) total FROM colores c
JOIN productos p
  ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN listado_productos lp
  ON p.producto = lp.producto
  AND c.color = lp.color
GROUP BY c.color, p.producto
ORDER BY p.producto, c.color;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ad82/1

---

Si no quieres modificar el esquema de tu base de datos, entonces podrías hacerlo consiguiendo lo mismo, todas las combinaciones de colores y productos, pero esta vez usando `DISCTINCT` para obtener los diferentes valores y, posteriormente, contar de nuevo aquellos que no sean `NULL`:

```
SELECT
  p.producto,
  c.color,
  COUNT(lp.producto)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(producto) FROM productos) p
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(color) FROM productos) c
  ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN productos lp
  ON p.producto = lp.producto
  AND c.color = lp.color
GROUP BY p.producto, c.color
ORDER BY p.producto, c.color;
```

También tienes un ejemplo en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ab21/1

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudó y me lo apunto!